# Fail to ignore SAX feature in unit test but successful in program running

Tags: java, jaxb, sax

I ignore a feature as following

`SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
spf.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);`

Why does the second line throw an exception in unit test but not happend in program running?
`org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Feature 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing' is not recognized.?`

Comment: can you show us the test case

Answer (score 0):

You have a different implementation or version of the SAX parser in your two environments.  You can determine the implementation by looking at the concrete impl class of `SAXParserFactory`.